# iPad wake up to an app

Tags: ipad, ios

Is there a way I can set my iPad to always open a particular ap when I wake it up (open my smart cover)?

I'm specifically interested in doing this with a text editor.

Comment: The app would need to be open when you close the cover. AFAIK it is standard behavior for any open app to resume when opening the smartcover.

Comment: This is contrary to the particular distinction made by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote Peek](http://blog.evernote.com/2011/06/08/introducing-evernote-peek-the-first-ipad-smart-cover-app/) can do this. It's an app which allows you to close your smartcover (don't know if you have one) and when reopening it, the app is still open.
So, yes it's possible.